# create document set on root site using spd workflow from subsite: forbidden error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow, power-automate

I am trying to create document set in a SharePoint list of Root site collection using a SPD workflow. I have created this workflow on SharePoint list in subsite of this Root site collection. I want to create document set in upper level of site when i create new item in a list of subsite.

Although i have applied all the permissions and trying to run using Global Admin account I am getting "Forbidden" error in response code of Rest Call.

Though I can run this workflow successfully from when i try to create document set on the same subsite level where the workflow is.

Details of workflow are:
It is SharePoint 2013 Workflow,
Which runs on creation of new item in a list in Subsite

I am using Http call for post call in App step.
Below are steps of workflow:

1. Build dictionary for headers and other parameters
   [image]
2. REST Call in App step.
   [image]

Another way i have tried is using MS Flow, which gives the same `Forbidden` error before i complete the steps for REST Call.
Is this possible to create document set on root site using workflow on subsite?
Or is there any other option to achieve this?